# Deleting all Transcribe Jobs in one CLI Command for AWS

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I am trying to delete all of my AWS Transcribe jobs at the same time. I know I can go through and delete them one by one through the console, and I can also delete them all through the CLI through the following command:

```
$ aws transcribe delete-transcription-job --transcription-job-name YOUR_JOB_NAME
```

The issue with this is that I have to do this for each individual job! I am dealing with them on a mass scale (about 1000 jobs). I have tried the following code, however this does not work:

```
for jobName in ${aws transcribe list-transcription-jobs --query '[TranscriptionJobSummaries[*].TranscriptionJobName]' --output text}; do aws delete-transcription-job --transcription-job-name $jobName
```

When I run this code, it does nothing. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Not 100% sure on this one, but what I am fairly certain about is that your `aws` command should be wrapped in `$()` not `${}`

Comment: @JNevill I had it with `()` before, and tried `{}`, however both produce the same outcome :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect to have a large number of values returned by the `list-transcription-jobs` command, then a `for` loop may hit argument list limits. In situations like this it's better to use a `while read` loop instead, for example:

```
aws transcribe list-transcription-jobs --query '[TranscriptionJobSummaries[*].TranscriptionJobName]' --output text | while read jobName; do
    aws delete-transcription-job --transcription-job-name "$jobName"
done
```

Comment: I've tried this method, and the first half works, however it fails to complete the other half. It can list the jobs for me no problem, however when it goes to Delete using the information provided, it displays nothing. It appears its is still processing, but checking the transcribe on the console, it still shows all of the jobs. Any ideas?

```aws transcribe list-transcription-jobs --max-results 100 --query '[TranscriptionJobSummaries[*].TranscriptionJobName]' --output text
while read jobName; do
    aws delete-transcription-job --transcription-job-name "$jobName"
done```

Comment: @OwenMurray The command you pasted prints maximum 100 results. If this is the command you used in the loop, then only the first 100 results would be deleted. Could this explain what you're observing? Have you tried without using `--max-results 100` ?

Comment: Apologies, I changed it to a maximum of 1 as it was printing 5 results at a time, I have it working now, thanks for the help! :)